# I am noticing double entry (cpc and organic) for the same user ? little confused

Tags: google-analytics

I'm noticing double entry in google analytics. I have multiple ocurrences where it looks like the user came from the CPC campaign (which always has a 0s session duration) but that very same user also has an entry for "organic" and all the activities are logged under that.

My site is not ranked organically for those keywords. Unless a so many users come to my site, leave, and google for my "brand name" on google and revisits, this doesn't make sense.

I'm a little confused. Here's the report:

[preview from google analytics dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uQB7.png)

Comment: Can you verify, if for any reason you are sending multiple pageview hits for a single page view? E.g. by accident, or for tracking the page views of a Single-Page-Application?

Comment: Yeah, it's tacking page views for a SPA. It's a nuxt.js app and every route change it fires a page view tag on GTM

Comment: The page views are correctly logged. But it's just logging it under the wrong category. It should be ppc but logs under organic which is wierd

Answer (score 0):

Based on the additional information in your comment, that the sites is a Single Page Application (SPA), you are most likely facing the problem of 'Rogue Referral'.

If this is the case, what happens, is that you overwrite the `location` field in the Analytics hit, losing the original UTM parameters, whereas referral is still sent with the hit, so Analytics recognizes the second hit as a new traffic source. One of the solutions is to store the original page URL and send it as the `location`, while sending the actual visited URL in the `page` field.

A very good [article on this topic](https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/fix-rogue-referral-problem-single-page-sites/) with further tips, by Simo Ahava, is available for your help.

Also please note, that as you have mentioned, that the first hit shows 0 second time on page, you might need to check, whether the first visited page is sent twice. E.g. sending a hit on the traditional page load event, and sending a hit for the same page as a virtual page view.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution to this problem in a Gatsby website (a SPA), by writing the main logic in the `gatsby-browser.js` file, inside the `onRouteUpdate` function.

You can use this solution in other contexts, but please note that the code needs to run at the first load of the page and at every route change.

If you want the solution to work in browsers that do not support `URLSearchParams` I think you can easily find a polyfill.

### Function to retrieve the parameters

```js
// return the whole parameters only if at least one of the desired parameters exists
const retrieveParams = () => {
  let storedParams;
  if ('URLSearchParams' in window) {
    // Browser supports URLSearchParams
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);
    const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
    const requestedParams = ['utm_source', 'utm_medium', 'utm_campaign', 'utm_content', 'gclid'];
    const hasRequestedParams = requestedParams.some((param) => {
      // true if it exists
      return !!params.get(param);
    });
    if (hasRequestedParams) {
      storedParams = params;
    }
  }
  return storedParams;
}
```

#### Create the full URL

```js
// look at existing parameters (from previous page navigations) or retrieve new ones
const storedParams = window.storedParams || retrieveParams();
let storedParamsUrl;
if (storedParams) {
  // update window value
  window.storedParams = storedParams;
  // create the url
  const urlWithoutParams = document.location.protocol + '//' + document.location.hostname + document.location.pathname;
  storedParamsUrl = `${urlWithoutParams}?${storedParams}`;
}
```

#### Send the value to analytics (using gtag)

```js
// gtag
gtag('config', 'YOUR_GA_ID', {
  // ... other parameters
  page_location: storedParamsUrl ?? window.location.href
});
```

or

```js
gtag('event', 'page_view', {
  // ... other parameters
  page_location: storedParamsUrl ?? window.location.href,
  send_to: 'YOUR_GA_ID'
})
```